# Share data between two div using same controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two div's with same controller, both div have almost same data to display. both div's have a button which updates an object. But when one div's button update the object it does not reflect on second div.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    {{list.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add('hi')">add</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    {{list.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add1('hello')">add</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller('ctrl1',function($scope){
  $scope.list={
    greet:'hola'
  }
  $scope.add=function(data){
    $scope.list.greet=data
  }
   $scope.add1=function(data){
    $scope.list.greet=data
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between controllers and different instances of the same controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('ctrl1', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.a = myService.list;
    $scope.add = function(data) {
      $scope.a.greet.push(data);
    }
  })
  .service('myService', function() {
    this.list = {greet: []};
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Ctrl1: <br>
    {{a.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add('c1a')">add</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Ctrl1: <br>
    {{a.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add('c1b')">add</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i wannted kinda use same controller

Comment: You can use the same controller... I updated the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Both the divs have an `ng-controller` attribute. This means each div has its own instance of the controller. Try adding the ng-controller to a common parent element

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <div>
    {{list.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add('hi')">add</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{list.greet}}
    <button ng-click="add1('hello')">add</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the scenario is different i just gave a small example here. actually both div is a popup which i have created using directive and added

Comment: In that case you probably want to use a service which stores the data and inject it into the controller (http://plnkr.co/edit/SWBjOjWYbP1rfPflvS80?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different ng-controller directives, each div will have its own scope.

The easiest option would be to use the $rootScope.

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller('ctrl1',['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.list={
    greet:'hola'
  }
  $scope.add=function(data){
    $rootScope.list.greet=data
  }
   $scope.add1=function(data){
    $rootScope.list.greet=data
  }
}]);
```